# Search Nearest Place API for Running Rout OR Jogging Trac types

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, google-places-api

Is there any API is available for searching nearest place from current location ? I know we can find via Google Place API/ Foursquare. and i have already worked on find pizza, bar cafe , bar like that, But my filter types is Running Rout OR Jogging Trace.

Please suggest me API name for same. OR is it possible to search same with Google Place API ?

Comment: google place api gives you all nearest place results . you need that api ?

Comment: You can get all nearest place data in this api . right ?

Comment: this link is useful for you so please upvote my answer.

Comment: hear no any one parameter for searching the jogging track or running road , please tell me

Comment: you can try to getting your nearest road name and any routes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this api for getting your current location around places and nearest all places results in this google api . you can add only your current location coordinates . see this api.
only replace %7C to |.

[See This Google api for all nearest places](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=9.934866,76.267235&radius=50000&types=country%7Cairport%7Camusement_park%7Cbank%7Cbook_store%7Cbus_station%7Ccafe%7Ccar_rental%7Ccar_repair%7Cchurch%7Cdoctor%7Cfire_station%7Cfood%7Chindu_temple%7Chospital%7Clawyer%7Clibrary%7Cmosque%7Cmuseum%7Cpark%7Cparking%7Cpharmacy%7Cpolice%7Cpost_office%7Crestaurant%7Cschool%7Ctrain_station%7Czoo&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAQZ16VzshxGbYdiM8C2RhhwGl3QwVJTB4)

i hope this link useful for you .